# error at java.util.Stack.peek/pop(Unknown Source) with if else

Tags: java

I have a task to make a stack calculator and this is what I've got:

```
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("1");
    commands.add("2");
    commands.add("3");
    commands.add("4");
    commands.add("+");
    commands.add("+");
    commands.add("+");
    commands.add("2");
    commands.add("*");
    commands.add("=");
    System.out.println(commands); //prints the list
    System.out.println(computeResult(commands));
    commands.clear();
    commands.add("2");
    commands.add("4");
    commands.add("/");
    commands.add("=");
    System.out.println(commands); //prints the list
    System.out.println(computeResult(commands)); // gives 2
    commands.clear();
    commands.add("3");
    commands.add("4");
    commands.add("-");
    commands.add("=");
    System.out.println(commands); //prints the list
    System.out.println(computeResult(commands)); // gives 1
    }

public static int computeResult(ArrayList<String> commands) {
    Stack<Integer> dataStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Iterator<String> commandsIterator = commands.iterator();
    while(commandsIterator.hasNext()) {

        /* sums up the two top elements from the stack and pushes the solution back on the stack
         * @param int A, int B, int C
         * @return
         */

        if(commands.contains("+")) {
            int A = dataStack.pop();
            int B = dataStack.pop();
            int C = A + B;
            dataStack.push(C);
        }

        /* subtract the two top elements from the stack and pushes the solution back on the stack
         * @param int A, int B, int C
         * @return
         */

        else if(commands.contains("-")) {
            int A = dataStack.pop();
            int B = dataStack.pop();
            int C = B - A;
            dataStack.push(C);
        }

        /* multiplies the two top elements from the stack and pushes the solution back on the stack
         * @param int A, int B, int C
         * @return
         */

        else if(commands.contains("*")) {
            int A = dataStack.pop();
            int B = dataStack.pop();
            int C = A * B;
            dataStack.push(C);  
        }

        /* divides the two top elements of the stack and pushes the solution back on the stack
         * @param int A, int B, int C
         * @return
         */

        else if(commands.contains("/")) {
            int A = dataStack.pop();
            int B = dataStack.pop();
            int C = B / A;
            dataStack.push(C);
        }

        /* pops the top element
         * @return popped element
         */

        else if(commands.contains("=")) {
            return dataStack.peek();
        }

        /* if the command is a number it will be assigned to an integer and pushed on the stack
         * @param int i, String command
         * @return
         */

        else {
            String command = commandsIterator.next();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(command);
            dataStack.push(i);
        }
     }
    return 0;
  }
```

But the problem is that I get the above error as output.
In this programm I used the if else to check if my input is an operator or a number and if its a number then I push the number, if its an operator I pop the two top elements and make the calculation. The result is again pushed so I thought it shouldn't be a problem.
I know what this error means so my question is how to solve it in this particular case.

Comment: Don't set a 4 lines comment that looks like full javadoc when just 1 line is usefull ;)

Comment: yeah we should do it like that for uni ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making a mistake here

> commands.contains("+")

I think your idea iterator to all item of `computeResult` to check if that item is an operator or a number, right ?
But if you call `commands.contains("+")` function, this will always return true if your `commands` contains `+` character no matter `+` in what position.

So my little fixed is

```
while (commandsIterator.hasNext()) {

    String s = commandsIterator.next();
    /* sums up the two top elements from the stack and pushes the solution back on the stack
     * @param int A, int B, int C
     * @return
         */
        if (s.equals("+")) {

        ...
        else if (s.equals("-"))
        ...

        else {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            dataStack.push(i);
        }
}
```

I've tried it. Work like a champ :) Hope that help :)

Comment: oh thanks a lot
I will try it like this
thank you now it's working fine

Comment: No problem :) If this solve your problem, you may accept my answer :)

Comment: Yes for sure ;D
It saved me a little ;D

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error, because your implementation of computeResult checks if the "commands"-list 'contains' these strings. And as the whole list DOES actually contain it, you try to pop items off the stack that don't exist.

So in short, the first if clause will already be executed and cause the error.

Try to debug your computeResult method.

Comment: Can you explain how I can just compare the first, cause I thought the while statement is exactly therefor?

Comment: Check @Ryann s answer for a more detailed answer :).

Comment: Saw it too late :D